# A topology on $\Bbb R^2$ not second countable

Tags: general-topology

Let us consider $\Bbb R^2$ with the topology $\tau$ consisting of all subsets which contain an open line segment in each direction about each of its points.

**Question.** Show that the topology $\tau$ on $\Bbb R^2$ is not second countable.

In fact, we know that the Euclidean topology is properly contained in $\tau$ by [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2908149/is-this-topology-a-subset-of-the-euclidean-topology)  .

Could anyone give me a hint?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Following up on the answer to your previous question, what is the subspace topology on $S^1$ induced by $\tau$?

Comment: Every subspace of a second-countable space is second countable. Thanks!